# yum Error: unsupported file format

Tags: linux, yum

I get the error as following.
my linux is centos5.

```
yum list
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
Error: unsupported file format
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is coming from sqlite, which is pretty bad. You can do:

yum clean dbcache

...and it should work. If that doesn't then the "yum clean all" hammer will fix the problem.
 It's kind of weird for any of the sqlite files to get corrupted though, you might want to check smart data etc. (make sure you don't have general FS corruption).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have modified files  /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo or have you added any new repo path to the directory /etc/yum.repos.d/ ..?